# MYSQL - Detectar quebra em sequencia, com condicionais

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Olá estou precisando de ajuda para fazer uma query ou procedure para detectar lacunas em um campo numérico,
tenho uma tabela de notas fiscais, a qual possui um campo num_nfe, ele deve seguir uma sequencia, não podendo existir lacunas nas numerações e devo fazer a verificação em outro campo, o campo status.

A query deveria verificar quais os registros não existem e também quais os registros tem o campo status diferente de "Emitida" ou "Cancelada".

Estou tentando algo nesse estilo:

```
SELECT j1.num_nfe +1 AS id
FROM nfe j1
LEFT JOIN nfe j2 ON j2.num_nfe = j1.num_nfe +1
WHERE j2.num_nfe IS NULL 
AND (
DATE_FORMAT( j1.dt_emissao,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) 
BETWEEN  '2018-03-01'
AND  '2018-04-30'
)  AND status in('Cancelada','Emitida')
AND j1.num_nfe <> ( 
SELECT MAX( num_nfe ) 
FROM nfe) 
ORDER BY j1.num_nfe
```

Comment: Consegue nos passar um cenário de como está e como gostaria que ficasse, apenas para visualizarmos melhor o problema?

Comment: Eu tentei fazer algo nesse estilo: `SELECT j1.num_nfe +1 AS id
FROM nfe j1
LEFT JOIN nfe j2 ON j2.num_nfe = j1.num_nfe +1
WHERE j2.num_nfe IS NULL 
AND (
DATE_FORMAT( j1.dt_emissao,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) 
BETWEEN  '2018-03-01'
AND  '2018-04-30'
)  AND status in('Cancelada','Emitida')
AND j1.num_nfe <> ( 
SELECT MAX( num_nfe ) 
FROM nfe) 
ORDER BY j1.num_nfe`

Comment: você pode editar sua pergunta para mostrar o que já tentou e o cenário. Assim fica mais fácil visualizar.

Comment: grosso modo select * from nfe where not exists (select null from nfe nfe2 where nfe2.num_nfe -1 = nfe.num_nfe) -- nao existe a anterior

Comment: Não existe a anterior, mas se por exemplo for inserido um intervalo de diferença com mais de um numero ele não detecta, por exemplo, se alguém ao invés de digitar 10, digitar 100 ele não mostra de 11 à 99 por exemplo.  e também não funciona no caso de registros que existem porem estão com o status diferente.

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/237229-falha-na-numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ uma outra solução para Oracle , rownum  é uma pseudo column que creio não exista no Mysql